# Run python script through Java with files arguments

Tags: java, python, file

I have a standard Maven project and I want to run the [meTypeset](https://github.com/MartinPaulEve/meTypeset) script. This script takes 3 args where the second one is a file and the third one is a folder created as output.

This is how the script runs in a cmd:

```
meTypeset.py docx <input> <output_folder> [options]
```

This is how I try to run it in Java:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] cmd = {
            "python",
            "resources\\pyscripts\\meTypeset.py",
            "docx",
            "resources\\exampledocs\\example_journal.docx",
            "resources\\output"
    };
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Nothing happens, no errors but no result also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike python Java may need some help. Do I guess correctly you are running on Windows?

You invoke the [Runtime.exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method. The method returns a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) instance, and in it's documentation you can read

> By default, the created process does not have its own terminal or
> console. All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations
> will be redirected to the parent process, where they can be accessed
> via the streams obtained using the methods getOutputStream(),
> getInputStream(), and getErrorStream(). The parent process uses these
> streams to feed input to and get output from the process. Because some
> native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input
> and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read
> the output stream of the process may cause the process to block, or
> even deadlock.

So it is likely your process is started by the OS but gets blocked due to I/O restrictions. Get around that by reading the STDOUT and STDERR streams until your process finishes. One good programming model is visible at https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java

Answer (score 3):

@Hiran Chaudhuri explained the error correctly. I am just posting how I solved it, thanks to @ Sonnenhut comment.

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] commands = {
            "python",
            "src\\main\\resources/pyscripts/meTypeset.py",
            "docx",
            "src\\main\\resources/exampledocs/example_journal.docx",
            "src\\main\\resources/output"
    };
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

// Read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

// Read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```